# How to create nested diamond shape using CSS?

Tags: html, css, shapes, css-shapes

I can do a diamond but I don't know how to nested diamond. I want to have a site that uses CSS Diamonds, I've attached an image to give a better idea of what I am looking at doing

[image]

Here is my HTML so far: http://codepen.io/thehung1724/pen/JBaIE

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-feature">
  <div class="feature-icon">
    <div class="icon">
      <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**LESS:**

```
.col-feature{
.feature-icon{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: inline-block;

    &:before{
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        border: 1px solid #444444;
        .rotate(45);
        .transition(border-color 0.3s);
    }

    &:before{
        left:5px;
        top:0;
        right:-5px;
        bottom:0;       
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Make multiple `<div>`s as a diamond class,loop from the top add a few pixel padding between them vertically, then build your diamond in each div? (may or may not be possible, just an idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use both `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/8efLr/1/

```
.feature-icon {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.feature-icon:before{
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    content: "";
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid #444444;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s;
}
.feature-icon:after {
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    content: "";
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-top:-5px;

    border: 1px solid #444444;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does rotating not work?

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(45deg); /* opera */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=5); /*for IE*/
```